# Perl : Dereference between @_ and $_

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine, dereference

I have a question with the following Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %dmax=("dad" => "aaa","asd" => "bbb");
my %dmin=("dad" => "ccc","asd" => "ddd");

&foreach_schleife(\%dmax,\%dmin);

sub foreach_schleife {
        my $concat;
        my $i=0;

        foreach my $keys (sort keys %{$_[0]}) {
                while ($_[$i]) {
                        $concat.="$_[$i]{$keys} ";
                        print $_[$i]{$keys}."\n";
                        $i++;
                }
                $i=0;
                $concat="";
        }
}
```

The Output is:

```
   bbb
   ddd
   aaa
   ccc
```

I don't understand this.
Normally you must dereference references on hashes,arrays etc. 
Why not here? Its enough to write :

```
$_[$i]{$keys}."\n";
```

and not something like that:

```
$$_[$i]{$keys}."\n";
```

Why?
Has it something to do with the speciality of the variable `@_`/`$_`?

Comment: if you're satisfied with an answer, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) it by pressing on the hollow green check mark next to it. It gives reputation to both you and the person whose answer you accepted, and is generally a good gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@_` is the array of subroutine arguments, hence `$_[$index]` accesses the element at `$index`

Dereferencing is only good if you have references, but `@_` isn't one.

Comment: Ok @_ is no reference but its elements are.But i think the second reply to my posting give the probable right answer.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that because an array (or a hash, for that matter) can only contain hash *references* your second act of indexing means that the reference is *understood*.

I think the developers need to document this a little better.

To see that it is not special to `*_`, you can try this before the loop:

```
my @a = @_;
```

And this during:

```
print $a[$i]{$keys}."\n";
```

I think the main thing is that if you *only* have a scalar reference as the base, then at least one `->` is required. So

```
my ( $damxr, $dminr ) = @_;
```

would require

```
$dmaxr->{ $key };
```

Comment: +1. In my opinion that short-hand notation is only useful for golfing, since it doesn't make sense even to seasoned Perl developers.

Comment: @flesk, you're entitled to your opinion. I think having a lot of `->` is excessive noise, if all you want to do is index.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you don't have to dereference `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` is that `$_[$i]{$keys}` is a valid short-hand notation for `$_[$i]->{$keys}` when your reference is in an array or a hash.

`$$_[$i]{$keys}` won't work, because it will try to dereference the special variable `$_` to a scalar. The correct syntax is `%{$_[$i]}`, but then you'll have to use `%{$_[$i]}->{$keys}`, which is more verbose.